# help to Identify MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro

I'm trying to buy new laptop, and one seller has three different laptops, but I can't figure out what the difference between new (2012) models of Apple MacBook Pro: MD104RS/A, MD104Z/A, MD104LL/A ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Meaningful differences between these models are keyboard and power plug.
RS/A is for Russian/former USSR market, Z/A is designated as international(do not know what it means practically) and LL/A is for US/Canadian market.